# Future pointing light cones in Black Hole in Schwarzschild Coordinates

Tags: general-relativity

In examining black holes in Schwarzchild Coords (ie without resorting to other coords) the r coord becomes timeline within the event horizon and the t coord spacelike.

Therefore the light cone is tilted by 90 degrees. However, how do we say which direction in r is future and which is past? (textbooks jump to the forward light cone being radially inward with minimal explanation).

This question is further complicated by the theoretical existence of white holes (even though they are not thought to be a physical reality) where the future light cone is pointing radially outwards. Is there a less hand wavy approach to explaining all of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't expect an explanation if you stick to singular coordinates,
where there is no smooth way to go from without to within.

Shift to well-behaved coordinates (e.g. Kruskal-Szekeres). Then
light-cones behaviour is quite simple and you may easily see which
their relationship must be wrt to Schwarzschild coordinates.

In K-S coordinates light-like geodetics are all at 45°, $t=$ const
lines are straight lines through the origin, $r=$ const lines are
equilateral hyperbolas with 45° asymptotes (see e.g. wikipedia article
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal-Szekeres_coordinates for
help).